# How can I extract all the coefficients of a linear equation?

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

I have a linear equation in two variables that I am simplifying using simplify from sympy and I want to extract all the coefficients of the equation. This is what I have for the coefficients of x and y

```
expr =(x - 4.48e10)**2 + (y+1.047e11)**2 - (x + 1.346e11)**2 - (y + 5.23e10)**2
smpl = simplify(expr)
smpl.as_expr()

x = smpl.coeff(x)
print(x)

y = smpl.coeff(y)
print(y)
```

How can I extract 7.88332*10^21 separately? I tried to use `a = smpl.coeff(-1)` but that prints out the absolute value of x and the last term. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your expression:

```
In [15]: smpl
Out[15]: -358800000000.0⋅x + 104800000000.0⋅y - 7.88332e+21
```

You want to get the constant term `7.88332e+21` separately from the rest of the expression. There are many different ways that you could do that depending on what other expressions you might want to handle.

When working interactively the simplest way to access parts of an expression is by using `.args` (possibly recursively) e.g.:

```
In [16]: smpl.args
Out[16]: (-7.88332e+21, 104800000000.0⋅y, -358800000000.0⋅x)

In [17]: smpl.args[0]
Out[17]: -7.88332000000000e+21

In [18]: smpl.args[2]
Out[18]: -358800000000.0⋅x

In [19]: smpl.args[2].args[0]
Out[19]: -358800000000.000
```

This makes it possible to find any subexpression manually but is a fragile approach to use in a program where the exact form of the expression might not be known ahead of time.

Other solutions really depend on defining what "class" of expressions you want to be able to handle and how exactly to specify which part of the expression is the part that you want. Assuming that your expression is always a polynomial with explicit numeric coefficients and your goal is to get the numeric constant then you can use `.as_coeff_Add`:

```
In [21]: smpl.as_coeff_Add()
Out[21]: (-7.88332e+21, -358800000000.0⋅x + 104800000000.0⋅y)

In [22]: smpl.as_coeff_Add()[0]
Out[22]: -7.88332000000000e+21
```

More generally any expression can be treated as a polynomial and plain numeric coefficients can be extracted from that:

```
In [25]: smpl.as_coefficients_dict()
Out[25]: defaultdict(int, {1: -7.88332e+21, x: -358800000000.0, y: 104800000000.0})

In [26]: smpl.as_coefficients_dict()[1]
Out[26]: -7.88332000000000e+21

In [31]: smpl.as_coefficients_dict()[x]
Out[31]: -358800000000.000
```

Another possibility that could work for non-polynomial expressions but depends on the syntactic form of the expression is to use pattern matching:

```
In [37]: a, b, c = symbols('a, b, c', cls=Wild, exclude=[x, y])

In [38]: smpl.match(a*x + b*y + c)
Out[38]: {a: -358800000000.0, b: 104800000000.0, c: -7.88332e+21}

In [39]: smpl.match(a*x + b*y + c)[c]
Out[39]: -7.88332000000000e+21
```

Unlike `as_coeff_Add` and `as_coefficients_dict()` this would also work if the term you wanted to exact was an expression rather than just a number.

Lastly a simple way to get all numbers out of an expression is using `.atoms`:

```
In [41]: smpl.atoms(Float)
Out[41]: {-7.88332e+21, -358800000000.0, 104800000000.0}

In [42]: list(smpl.atoms(Float))
Out[42]: [-358800000000.0, 104800000000.0, -7.88332e+21]

In [43]: list(smpl.atoms(Float))[-1]
Out[43]: -7.88332000000000e+21
```